# KDB - using a gui client

Tags: kdb

I'm just getting started using KDB again.  At my old job everything was all set up on the server with a number of tables and I would just query the data.  I'm now loading in my own data files and want to be able to query it from a GUI client.

The two I used in the past were QStudio and QPadInsight.  For both of these, I need to connect to the server.  I'm pretty sure I need to have it listen to localhost since the server is running on my desktop computer where the client is also running.  I don't know what port to set it to.  Also, do I need to do anything to have the server running other than opening a command prompt and running Q (`c:\q\w32\q.q`)?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to set the port for connecting it via qpad.

However, you can also load a specific file in that session from the command prompt.

```
c:\q\w32>q server.q -p 1234   //load the server.q file in q session
KDB+ 3.5 2017.11.30 Copyright (C) 1993-2017 Kx Systems
q)
```

If you are just bringing up the q session then you have to set the port and load some server-specific code manually.

```
c:\q\w32>q
KDB+ 3.5 2017.11.30 Copyright (C) 1993-2017 Kx Systems
q)\l server.q 
q)\p 1234
```

Now it can be connected via qstudio or qpad using the connection string `` `::1234 ``

Check this out to set the [QHOME](https://code.kx.com/q/tutorials/install/#define-q-as-a-command)

You can set the `QINIT` variable to point to some q file that can act as the  bootstrap file for all the q sessions you will run on your box (e.g. helper functions)

You can add the commands to a `bat` file to avoid any manual steps.

```
set QHOME=C:\q
set QINIT=C:\code\server.q
set PATH=%PATH%;%QHOME%;%QHOME%\w32
q -p 1234
```

Comment: Thanks.  I got that working and am making some progress.  Now what I'd like to do is in a bat file have my csv data automatically get started.  I recreated this bat file from something old that I had.  REM set KDBALB=c:\q\files
set KDBPORT=9999
<br>
set PATH=%PATH%;c:\q\w32

REM launch the discovery service
start "KDB" q %KDBALB% -p %KDBPORT%    Now I want to in the bat file load the csv file.  How would I add customers: ("SSSSS"; enlist ",") 0:`c:/q/files/customers.csv to the bat file?  Thanks so much!

Comment: As i mentioned, create a server.q file ; add the code customers:("SSSSS"; enlist ",") 0:`:c:/q/files/customers.csv

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!  I definitely have a lot of playing around to do and am sure I will have a few more questions but you literally just saved me hours of research.  I now have all this data in QPad which is going to be huge.  One more time, thanks!